Merge [structure] into [sentence-structure]? What about [constructs]?
It seems to me that these tags are about the same thing. The dominant tag is sentence-structure with 243 questions and a tag wiki excerpt:

Questions concerning the types of words and phrases which are grouped and ordered meaningfully to express a statement, question, or another type of sentence

The tag structure has 19 questions and no tag wiki, all of which look like focusing on sentence structure:

How can I ask "which one is your favorite/do you like more"?
Are the sentences 这个杯子有一点儿水 and 一点儿水在杯子里 correct?
Correction of 我在饭店里把晚饭吃了
Is 靠 structure "A 靠 B do something"?
褒贬句 In chinese language
好 vs 住 (in resultative complement)
How do form "You can borrow the book once [it's returned / C returns in]" in Chinese?
How do form this sentence "I want (object) to (verb/be) that..." in Chinese?
Is '我还需要多加练习' okay as a dance video caption?
What does the '头' in '头一次遇到' mean?
Has anybody heard of 嵌套结构(nested structure)? The dictionary I use lists 中 as it instead of 单一结构
Give further examples of morphological alternation patterns such as Verb/Noun (处 chu3 / chu4) and Active/Inactive Verb (好 hao4 / hao3)
What contributes to negative emotion / sentiment in this example?
When will we use 来 and 到 after a verb?
Can I use 完 after all verb to say finish doing activities?
when will we use 没(mei3) and 不(bu4) before verb in sentences?
MacOS Keyboard with Predictive Completion produces 心情舒暢
How to say "we want what is best for our kids"?
When should 了 be after the verb and when should it be at the end of the sentence?

The difference between [sentence-structure] and [structure] doesn't seem meaningful enough to me. Are there other entities with structure that are not sentences, and that aren't more appropriately covered by another tag?

The other tag constructs has 7 questions, and no tag wiki:

Sentence construction with 除了, 被，一方面
了 vs 是...的 as "factuality markers"
Is this email correct grammatically and structurally?
Lists and Conjunctions
What is the term for alluding to a more formless concept by listing its specific members?
When is a degree required? or: hai6 vs hou2 vs gei
MSM equivalent of 倒...不... or 半...不... construct?

After further examination, this tag may have its own specific and correct meaning, as in "grammatical constructions":

a group of words that form a constituent of a sentence and are considered as a single unit;

For example ”是～的“，“快～了”, etc. So this tag might be fine, but:

it's almost unused
I wonder if it isn't adequately represented by grammar

Edit: proposed [structure] -> [sentence-structure] synonym

I wouldn't do the synonym: there are other forms of "structure" beyond "sentence-structure" (e.g. paragraph structure, like Is this email correct grammatically and structurally?).

[constructs] seems adequately covered with [sentence-structure] and [grammar].  Maybe it'd be nice to have this tag, but there's going to be hundreds of questions that need it---too much retagging effort.

@Becky李蓓 the linked question is not tagged [structure] though :) wouldn't it be weird with both [structure] and [sentence-structure]?
Anyway, feel free to vote on the synonym, including downvoting ;)

For structure, I edited many of these manually.  The structure was sometimes used for other things, like complement, or even just used seemingly at random.
After checking, I merged the remaining structure questions into sentence-structure.  I don't intend to create a synonym, as other aspects of Chinese also have structure (e.g. paragraph structure, character structure).  [It might be worth blacklisting the structure tag, since it's rather vague (I haven't done this).]

For constructs, I edited some of these manually (there's still a few which can be edited away).  I'm not quite sure what to do with this one:

Modern Standard Mandarin equivalent of the 倒...不... and 半...不... constructs?

But generally, if constructs refers to "grammar constructs" then it can be reasonably tagged grammar together with a more specific tag that describes the kind of construct (e.g. particles, sentence-structure).

as for the outstanding question, I've removed [constructs] and added: [grammar] (self-explanatory), [topolect] (because it's related to topolect usage) and [synonyms] (as it's requesting smt with similar meaning)
